# Problem facing with sorting the hyperlink column in Infragistic ultrawebgrid

Tags: infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I am facing an issue for sorting the hyperlink column in infragistic ultra webgrid. I'm using server side sort method to sort the column - `GD1_sortcolumn` and passing the asc, desc and other parameters accordingly bind the data in ultra webgrid it's working fine here and sorting is also working fine with Name column. For example I have passed the Name column and asc parameter then it calls sp with these parameters. I got the datatable with sorted values and bind the datatable with grid successfully.

The problems comes in the `GD1_InitializeRow` method when the hyperlink is created. Please find the below code:

```
private void GD1_InitializeRow(object sender, Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.RowEventArgs e)
{
     if (!(e.Row.Cells.FromKey("AgentName").Value.Equals(" ")))
     {    
                 e.Row.Cells.FromKey("Name").Text = "<A Href=\"javascript:AgentDetails('" + e.Row.Cells.FromKey("AgentId") + "','" + agentAcctID + "')\" class='GridAnchor'> " + e.Row.Cells.FromKey("AgentName").Text + "</a>";

      }    
}
```

In the above code I had passed the two parameters(`agentid` and `accountid`) in the JavaScript function. While binding the hyperlink column in above function. it's sorting the grid data with `agentid` asc in hyperlink column instead of showing the sort column with name asc.

Answer (score 0):

you can track the discussion frin [IG's official forum post](https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-asp-net/119880/not-able-to-sort-the-hyperlink-column-in-infragistics-ultrawebgrid).